# Reuse styles in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there a way to reuse styles in an iOS app as it's done in android?
(or other approach, css-like, for example)

Like this:

styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/AppBackground</item>
</style>

<!-- Search Bar -->
<style name="AppTheme.SearchBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/searchBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/search_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
</style>
//...
```

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/searchBar"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Table"
    >
    //...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, not any direct one-to-one solutions. You can use UIView subclasses (which can obviously fall apart without multiple inheritance) or try to use some general pattern like composition to make sure UI elements have a similar style (but this would need to be done in actual code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: You will either need to manually set the styles on each view, OR you could extend the components (or create your own subclasses) which implements the styles you want.

Comment: Ok, I think I hate iOS now. Thanks ^^

Comment: :P Sadly Android does stuff like that much, much better than iOS.

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries which you should take a look at including Freestyle (http://www.freestyle.org), UISS (https://github.com/robertwijas/UISS), NUI (https://github.com/tombenner/nui) and MAThemeKit (https://github.com/mamaral/MAThemeKit).

Also check out the documentation for `UIAppearance`.